# Does Apache Parquet support full-text search?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, full-text-search, parquet

I have files stored in AWS S3 in Parquet format and want to know if we can run full-text search queries on Parquet files. If so, how to go about doing it? Or are there any work arounds to enable full-text search on Parquet? Thanks in advance.

Looked at the Jira issue tracker on Parquet website but couldn't find relevant answers.

Comment: Parquet is just a storage format, like an XLS file or a CSV file. It doesn't offer any computing in itself. To perform searches, you would need to use a Query Engine that can read and process the Parquet file, such as Amazon Athena or Spark. Mind you, "full text search" is different to running SQL queries, so it isn't simple. Worst case, you could send the data to Elastic for storage and processing.